# How to install R packages in R provided by my school

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

My university provides access to RStudio via VPN. I can access but I can't install packages I usually can install on my PC. I know it's broad question, but any ideas on what to do?

This is what I get when I try to install:

```
> install.packages("tm")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  object 'status' not found
Installing package into ‘/sscc/home/w/wgm210/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  object 'status' not found
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tm’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)
> install.packages("tm", lib="/sscc/opt/R-3.3.2/lib64/R/library")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  object 'status' not found
Warning in install.packages :
  'lib = "/sscc/opt/R-3.3.2/lib64/R/library"' is not writable
Would you like to use a personal library instead?  (y/n) y
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  object 'status' not found
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tm’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)
```

Comment: Your school runs R 3.3.2; CRAN only keep binaries for the current R major, which is R 3.4.3 right now.  You could try install from source, but then you may need a compiler.

Comment: I'd request your school to upgrade the R version. It's quite simple for the admins to do it. At my university, it usually takes less than 24hr. Just a headsup that R 3.4.4 is coming out next week

Answer (score 0):

Ask your root user to make "/sscc/opt/R-3.3.2/lib64/R/library" path writable.

```
sudo chmod 777 /sscc/opt/R-3.3.2/lib64/R/library
```